# Pandas pd.DataFrame converts to Tuples instead of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I first use BeautifulSoup:

```
mydivs = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "content"})
```

so that each `mydiv` in `mydivs` looks like this for example:

```
<div class="content">A number of hats by me <br/><br/>three now though ... </div>
```

I then want to store each of the text blocks in each `div` as rows in a dataframe. I want the dataframe to look something like:

```
index posts
0     <div class="content">A number of  <br/><br/>three  ... </div>
1     <div class="content">Stack ... <br/><br/>overflow  ... </div>
...
```

This is the code I tried

```
A=[]
indices=[]
j=0

for div in mydivs:
    A.append(div)
    indices.append(j)
    j+=1

DF = pd.DataFrame({'index': indices, "posts": A})
```

When I then print out the `shape` I get

```
print DF.shape()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

However, I want `DF` to be a dataframe, not a `tuple`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shape is an attribute of `DF`. That attribute is a `tuple`. You are trying to call it with the `()` which is throwing the error. If you want the shape just do `DF.shape`

```
print DF.shape
```

***not***

```
print DF.shape()
```